# How can I make the command pattern thread safe?

Tags: java, design-patterns

In the command executor two methods are there.One is used to record the audit log and the next one is used to save the audit log to a DB. The application will record the audit information from different process of the application and at the end of each process it invokes the run method to finally save the audit information into DB.

An ArrayList is used to store all audit information along with the event that has generated this audit data.The Arraylist is now shared across all the process. I have only one instance of CommandExecutor shared for all the process.

My problem is to make it thread-safe for all the processes.

```
@Service 
public class CommandExecutor {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CommandExecutor.class);

private final ArrayList<TransactionAudit> transactionRecordList = new ArrayList<TransactionAudit>();

@Autowired
private TransactionService transactionService;

@Autowired
private TransactionDAO transactionDAO;

/**
 * Record the audit data at the collector points. At this point audit mayn't
 * be saved
 * 
 * @param tAudit
 * @return
 */
public void record(TransactionAudit audit) {
    transactionRecordList.add(audit);
}

/**
 * Audit data will be saved on call of run method. Till than the data will
 * in transactionRecordList.
 * 
 * @param key
 *            - Unique get the recorded audit data.
 */
public void run() {
    transactionRecordList.forEach((audit)->{
    transactionDAO.saveAudit(audit);
  });
  transactionRecordList.clear();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.   (1) Learn what "thread-safe" means; (2) Modify your code according to what you learned in step (1).  Multi-threaded programming is a large complex subject. We cannot teach you what you need to know here, and we certainly are not going to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the java.util.concurrent package.

The only thing I see that needs to be done is change the implementation of List you are using, so instead of ArrayList, use CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Also declare transactionRecordList as List<> Interface Type, so even if you change the implementation, you can interact with your List just by the interface exposed API (Liskov Principle)

So it should become something like this:

```
private static final List<TransactionAudit> transactionRecordList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<TransactionAudit>();
```

Comment: The question isn't about making the transactionRecordList  thread-safe. The issue that I am trying to solve is with the command design pattern while working in a multithreaded environment. I can record different event and I amn't sure whether those will be saved in the right order. CommandExecutor is a singletone class and it's state can be modified by any thread.

Comment: Well, the command pattern would normally no have problems with multithreading. The issues would appear when you make the Command class try to retain information. Those issues would present as, retention, information loss due overwrite and other concurrency issues. So as long as you ensure that your status update and retrieval are "threadsafe" you should have cleared the problem

Comment: I am doing that using concurrenthasmap and mapping each of the event with a key. The run method will identify the with the key and save the audit. It will leave out the audit generated by other processes.Looking out for some best practices to solve the similar problem.